# How to Remove "nameOf in place of string" Error in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

On loading the solution in VisualStudio, I get tons of error with **"CA1507 Use nameof in place of string literal"** error.

I can suppress it or add nameOf in my code but I dont want that. Also, It is occurring in more than 300 places in the code and only I am getting this error in my team.

All other devs in my team are not getting this error when they load the sln file.

Actual code :

`[JsonProperty("code")] public string code { get; set; }`

Error gets remove when I do this (but why I need to do this and no other devs in my team) :

`[JsonProperty(nameof(code))] public string code { get; set; }`

Other devs are saying **some issue with how VS has loaded the solution**. Also, I can't use nameOf because JSON properties don't match property names

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0f98.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's an error? Not a warning? What is the error code? Please provide full details.

Comment: It’s not an error, it’s from [code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1507) and [can be turned off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings)

Comment: Have you looked at their code analysis config rules? They may have disabled the rule for all projects by setting severity to `none` (which you could also do to remove the warning).

Comment: It is an error, attached image for reference.

Comment: If it was an error, your code would not compile.

Comment: Yes, I am unable to compile it @stuartd.

Comment: Go into the project's config file and try to delete the TreatWarningsAsErrors line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if the letter case matches, then you don't need to add an attribute to the property.

```
 // This is an unnecessary attribute, because the case of the word `code` is the same.
[JsonProperty("code")]
public string code { get; set; }
```

Just remove the attribute.

---

The attribute makes sense if the property casing is different from the field casing in json.

```
// code != Code - no warning
[JsonProperty("code")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

---

You can always [Suppress  a warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1508#suppress-a-warning).

---

The fact that you get an error message instead of a warning means that the [TreatWarningsAsErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors) compiler option is enabled in the project.

Comment: Which file would have this flag ? How can I search it ?

Comment: @Learning7 - Solution Explorer > right click on project name > Edit Project File

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation for the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1507#how-to-fix-violations):

> *"To disable this entire category of rules, set the severity for the category to none in the [configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files)."*

[EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022)

```
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1507.severity = none
```

Comment: How do you open the config files ? like what name would it be ?

Comment: Did you read the configuration file page that I linked? I believe it specifies how to update an existing one and add a new one. I could copy that content here, but I thought the link might be better since it provides lots of context

Answer (score 0):

> why I need to do this and no other devs in my team

Check if you have a `.editorconfig` or `.ruleset` file on your machine that other devs don't have.

Adding an `.editorconfig` to version control that sets a specific severity will make the situation consistent across machines.